# What means "3rd level of" in the context of Compose keys?

Tags: keyboard, composition, kde-plasma

In the KDE System Settings > Keyboard > Advanced Tab when I want to establish the Compose key, it gives me several choices of keys and some have the alternative prefix "3rd level of". What does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

I found it myself. Apparently 1st and 2nd are the dead Shift and Ctrl keys, but there is a 3rd on many keyboard called ALT GR. After trying, this assumption seems correct.

Would be nice if someone could provide some background or a proper basis for this.